# Actualizar el valor del formcontrol en keyup

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estoy intentando que al escribir en los inputs el texto se convierta en mayúsculas, pero éste no se guarda en el valor del formcontrol.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="nombre" (keyup)="$event.target.value = $event.target.value.toUpperCase();">
</mat-form-field>
```

El resultado visible en el input es el deseado, pero el valor que se guarda el formcontrol no, ¿alguna idea de como actualizar también el valor del formcontrol mediante utilizando el evento?

Comment: esto puedes hacerlo con css => `input { 
  text-transform: capitalize;
}`

Comment: @LPZadkiel con `text-transform: uppercase` en este caso, no se actualiza el valor del formcontrol, solo el valor visible del input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puesto que estás usando `formControlName`, asumo que estás usando *reactive forms*.

Por tanto puedes observar los cambios en el formulario y actualizarlo, pasando a maýusculas:

```
this.dataForm.controls.nombre.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
  this.dataForm.controls.nombre.setValue(value.toUpperCase(), {emitEvent: false});
})
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-pawer13).

Nota: `{emitEvent: false}` es vital porque sin ese detalle caeríamos en un bucle infinito: al cambiar el valor del formControl se produce un evento `valueChanges`, que provocaría que la subscripción actuase de nuevo.